# Can the center of a group not contain the identity element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying for an exam and while reviewing my notes it urge this question if the center of a group cannot contain the identity element. My thought is that it is possible in non abelian groups but can somebody give me an specific example.

Comment: Do you know what the identity is, and what the center is? The center is the set of group elements that commute with all other group elements. If $e$ is the identity, does $e\cdot g=g\cdot e$ for all $g$ in a group $G$? Yes or no?

Comment: Thank you, I think i'm just tired. yes in all groups ⋅=⋅. so that means the identity is always in the center since Z(G)={g in G: for all h in G we have hg = gh}.

Comment: In fact, the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is always a *subgroup* of $G$. Prove that.

Answer (score 1):

The identity element commutes with every element, as $g\cdot1=g=1\cdot g$. Therefore, $1\in Z(G)=\{g\in G\mid hg = gh\:\forall\: h \in G\}$.

In fact, it is an easy exercise to prove that $Z(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$: "Closure" is clear, as if $h$ and $k$ commute with $g$ then $hk\cdot g=g\cdot hk$, while to obtain inverses note the following:
$$\begin{align*}
hg=gh&\Rightarrow hgh^{-1}=g &\text{multiply on right by}~h^{-1}\\
&\Rightarrow gh^{-1}=h^{-1}g &\text{multiply on left by}~h^{-1}
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, if $g$ and $h$ commute then so do $g$ and $h^{-1}$. Hence, if $h\in Z(G)$ then $h^{-1}\in Z(G)$. Therefore, $Z(G)\leq G$.

Comment: Alternatively for inverses, if $h$ is in the center, then for every $g\in G$, $hg^{-1}=g^{-1}h$. taking inverses, we get $gh^{-1}=h^{-1}g$ for all $g\in G$.